# Plotting Co2 Emissions Over Time Using Python

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib

The prompt of the project is as follows:
Project Overview:
This project will test your ability to read and interpret data from a .csv file, plot and analyze the data. The provided file “co2_data.csv” contains monthly atmospheric CO2 concentrations from January 1960 until
October 2022 (ref: https://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/carbon-dioxide/). The file contains 3 comma
separated values per row (year, month, ppm CO2). You will need to utilize file system operators such as
open() and csv.reader() to read and interpret the given data. Be sure to import “matplotlib”, “math”, and
“numpy” as needed.

1. (40 points) Develop python code to read and plot the values for CO2 concentrations for the entire
   data set. Be sure to choose line types/weights/markers to allow for clear reading of the data. Plot
   the data on a single graph and include axis titles and value markers.
2. (40 points) Develop code to determine the average CO2 concentrations for each calendar year.
   Plot this new data set on the same graph as generated in Part 1. Select a new line
   type/weight/marker to distinguish this data from the full data set plot.
3. (10 points) Format the graph outputs to easily view and interpret both graphical outputs. Include
   a legend for the full data set and average output on your graph.

Heres what I tried

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np

emissions = []
date = []
with open('co2_data.csv','r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
      
    for row in data:
        date.append(float(row[0]))
        emissions.append(float(row[2]))


plt.plot(date, emissions, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

This is what I tried but I get 12 values at the same point, 1960, when I would like them to be separated by month.

Comment: Right, because your `date` array consists of only the year.  You do not need the year to be a floating point number.  Build up a date string like "YYYY-MM" and make that the x axis.

Comment: It looks like you are just plotting the year, when you want to add month in some way - row[1].

Comment: You could get a lot more help if you provided the co2_data.csv file (just the first 12 lines would be sufficient).  But it's clear that you are ignoring the second column (assumed to be month).  Your code only references row[0] (the year) and row[2] (the value).  You'll need to "somehow" build the date from row[0] and row[1] in  a format acceptable to plt.plot.